# Implement ELSE expression from SQL data, is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there're 2 tables with data like below:

```
-- Table #Detail
TelNO      
---------- 
001xxxxx
020xxxxx
021xxxxx
800xxxxx
400xxxxx
28011111
82188888
22223333
...
...

-- Table #FeeRate
Expression Price   Description                                        
---------- ------- -------------------------------------------------- 
001%       10.00   International call
0[^0]%     5.00    National call
800%       .00     Free call
400%       .80     800 like, but caller need pay for local part
ELSE,How?  .20     Others/Local call
```

I want to select data from the 2 tables JOINed on `dbo.FUNCTION_Match (TelNO, Expression)` condition. (*`dbo.FUNCTION_Match` is a crude function i wroted to match `TelNO` and `Expression`. In this sample, you can treat it as `TelNO LIKE Expression`*).

So the SQL & query result is

```
SELECT * FROM #Detail d
    LEFT JOIN #FeeRate f ON d.TelNO LIKE f.Expression

TelNO      Expression Price   Description                                        
---------- ---------- ------- -------------------------------------------------- 
001xxxxx   001%       10.00   International call
020xxxxx   0[^0]%     5.00    National call
021xxxxx   0[^0]%     5.00    National call
800xxxxx   800%       .00     Free call
400xxxxx   400%       .80     800 like, but caller need pay for local part
28011111   NULL       NULL    NULL
82188888   NULL       NULL    NULL
22223333   NULL       NULL    NULL
```

The problem is clear, those local calls in #Detail can't matched `Others` FeeRate.

My crude FUNCTION_Match function has handled multi-expressions like `TelNO NOT LIKE '0%' AND TelNO NOT LIKE [84]00% OR TelNO LIKE '0755%'` to match `Others` FeeRate, but it's hard to write a correct multi-expression to express `ELSE` when there're many records in #FeeRate table.

So, is there a way to implement `ELSE` expression from data ?

---

**SQLs to create sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE #Detail (TelNO VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '')
CREATE TABLE #FeeRate (Expression VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '', Price NUMERIC(10,2) DEFAULT 0, Description VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '')

INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('001xxxxx')
INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('020xxxxx')
INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('021xxxxx')
INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('800xxxxx')
INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('400xxxxx')
INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('28011111')
INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('82188888')
INSERT INTO #Detail VALUES ('22223333')

INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('001%',  10.0, 'International call')
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('0[^0]%', 5.0, 'National call')
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('800%',   0.0, 'Free call')
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('400%',   0.8,  '800 like, but caller need pay for local part')
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('ELSE,How?',  0.2, 'Others/Local call')

SELECT * FROM #Detail
SELECT * FROM #FeeRate

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Detail d
    LEFT JOIN #FeeRate f ON d.TelNO LIKE f.Expression

DROP TABLE #Detail
DROP TABLE #FeeRate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra column to your `FeeRate` table, called `Priority`. Assign higher priorities to the matches that should occur "earlier". Do two joins to the fee rate table, the second being a left join, and looking for a higher priority match. If the left join works, reject the result row:

```
CREATE TABLE #FeeRate (Expression VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '', Price NUMERIC(10,2) DEFAULT 0, Description VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',Priority int)

INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('001%',  10.0, 'International call',5)
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('0[^0]%', 5.0, 'National call',4)
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('800%',   0.0, 'Free call',3)
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('400%',   0.8,  '800 like, but caller need pay for local part',2)
INSERT INTO #FeeRate VALUES ('%',  0.2, 'Others/Local call',1)

SELECT * FROM #Detail d
    inner JOIN #FeeRate f ON d.TelNO LIKE f.Expression
    left join #FeeRate f_anti on d.TelNo LIKE f_anti.Expression and f_anti.Priority > f.Priority
where
    f_anti.Price is null
```

This probably allows you to simplify some of your other expressions also.

Comment: wow, this is smart solution, it took me long time to figure out how it works (how to fiter out duplicated match), thanks! BTW, use `LEN(f_anti.Expression) > LEN(f.Expression)` to replace `f_anti.Priority > f.Priority` works too. Now i need to think about how to apply this solution to real environment.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one "other" category, store its values in variables and substitute them in when there is no match using `ISNULL`:

```
DECLARE @expression VARCHAR(20), @price NUMERIC (10,2), @description VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @expression = Expression, @price = Price, @description = [Description]
FROM #FeeRate 
WHERE Expression = 'ELSE,How?'

SELECT d.TelNO, ISNULL(f.Expression, @expression) AS Expression,
ISNULL(f.Price, @price) AS Price,
ISNULL(f.[Description], @description) AS [Description]  
FROM
    #Detail d
    LEFT JOIN #FeeRate f ON d.TelNO LIKE f.Expression
```

Comment: In real environment, there's another column in #FeeRate table named `ServiceProvider` (call via different ServiceProvider/trunk will have different price), There're 1+ `Others` category in #FeeRate table, but there's only 1 `Other` category in 1 `ServiceProvider`. Thanks anyways, it's a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure what data you are having in #Detail table, but for the above data you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
            #Detail d
                LEFT JOIN #FeeRate f ON 
                    (CASE 
                        WHEN d.TelNO LIKE '%xxxxx' THEN TelNO 
                        ELSE 'ELSE,How?' 
                     END) LIKE f.Expression
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, xxxxx here means any digits, not means literal xxxxx string.